# Why would adding header cables solve any problems?

Tags: pcb, fpga, sdram, header

I was trying to debug an FPGA to external SDRAM connection and I found that connecting cables to the pins of the address bus fixes the interface in some way. I want to know how/why.

[image: Something like this]

Things I'm pretty confident about:

- The voltage level (LVTTL.)
- Adding cables fixes the problem at a variety of clock frequencies (10-25 MHz), and removing them causes the interface to be bad at those same clock rates.

Ideas(?):

- Additional capacitance of the cables?
- The header pins by themselves act as antennas or something? They are about 1 cm tall so they would be antennas for 1.2 GHz signals? (Maybe 2.4 GHz WiFi as well.) I'm not an EE major, so this is really deep speculation

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? Probably not, from the sounds of it. Snip the cables incrementally shorter and see what you can get away with. It's probably a termination thing.

Comment: If the failing signal is of a somewhat high frequency, then slightly changing the capacitance/inductivity of it can definitely affect the signal.

Comment: @DKNguyen I unfortunately do not have a scope, but do I have a logic analyzer :D

Maybe I should've bought analog discovery instead of digital

[This is an example of what I see](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/21113951/133338751-50818178-222f-4b29-b50e-f3852d1a81c4.png (connecting the header cables to the logic analyzer)

Comment: Also @DKNguyen any resources for understanding the "termination thing"? I think I'd love to learn more!

Comment: Transmission lines, reflections, ringing http://helloworld922.blogspot.com/2013/04/online-transmission-line-simulation.html

Comment: Is this brand new equipment that you are designing with no previously working version?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm basically trying to get the Litex framework (https://github.com/enjoy-digital/litex) to work on my FPGA board (I just bought the board)

Comment: I ask because it's unclear whether it's not working because of a hardware fault or because you are developing FPGA code and it's the FPGA code that needs some kind of tweak.

Comment: Hmm, I'm fairly confident in the FPGA code (people smarter than me wrote the actual Verilog - https://github.com/enjoy-digital/litedram, and it seems to work fine on other boards - including other Cyclone IV boards). I'm just instantiating their design. 

It does however seem peculiar the exact circumstances of failure for me - there's some SDRAM test utility that passes but when trying to "actually use" the RAM with real traffic, it flakes out unless I add header cables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting extra capacitance to a bus will make the signals change more slowly, making it harder to meet setup times and easier to meet hold times at the receiving memory.

This is just another version of the well-known 'laying on of hands' method of debugging. Basically a good design will be resistant to slight changes in timing caused by adding a little extra capacitance, or a little extra load. When the design is on the edge, small changes can make a large difference between it working and not working, in either direction.

You've found a part of the board that is very sensitive to small changes. You must examine the design of all the timings around this interface, see what is being violated, and fix it.